# Was ist eine angemessene Übersetzung für "shitstorm"?

Tags: translation, single-word-request, idiom, noun

Was ist eine angemessene Übersetzung für "shitstorm"? Gibt es dafür ein deutsches Wort?

Comment: Ein Glück. In dict.cc ist es nicht drin. Was ist denn das genau? Nein. Warte. Ich will das gar nicht wissen.

Comment: It indeed would be nice if you could add an example sentence in English. ^^

Comment: Der Ausdruck "shitstorm" wird öfters genutzt wenn z. B. auf Twitter sich die Massen über etwas aufregen.

Comment: Bestimmt verwandt mit "the shit has hit the fan", oder? :-)

Comment: @Jan how very apt.  :D

Comment: Ich habe mal **Stuhlgewitter** gehört. Fand ich sehr passend.

Comment: Wie das Kommentar vor @ladybug andeutet, ist der Begriff "Shitstorm" den englischen Muttersprachlern unbekannt. Dies ist eine deutsche Wortschöpfung.

Comment: Was auf deutsch Shitstorm genannt wird, ist im Englischen eigentlich ein [flame war/ flamewar](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flame+war)

Comment: Ich beminusse die Frage. Eigentlich ist sie interessant, aber - wie man dann bei der Lektüre der Antworten sieht - es fehlt ihr die Erläuterung, welche der verschiedenen möglichen Verwendungsweisen von *shitstorm* eigentlich gemeint ist. Im Deutschen kenn tman *shitstorm* vor allem als *Massierung vulgärsprachlich-brutaler Negativkommentare im Internet*, aber es sieht so aus, als ob es im Englisch-Amerikanischen eine breitere Verwendung auch außerhalb des Internets hat oder hatte.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nachdem ich mir die Bedeutungen im [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shit%20storm) durchgelesen habe, ist glaube ich **am/im Arsch sein** auch eine ganz gute Übersetzung. (Siehe auch [hier](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=%7E%7Eim%20Arsch%20sein&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou).)

> Da kommt mein Chef. Gleich bin ich am Arsch.
>
> Tom war gestern nach der Party echt völlig im Arsch. (auch: am Arsch)
>
> Meine Frau hat mich verlassen, mein Haus ist abgebrannt und mein Job ist weg. Verdammt, ich bin total am Arsch.

Die dritte Bedeutung ("A euphemism qualifying a noun with a greater sense of intensity rather than as plainly stated."), auf die sich sicher auch der Twitter-Kontext bezieht, passt da leider gar nicht rein.

Einen "shit storm of controversy" könnte man evtl. mit einem "Sturm der Entrüstung" wiedergeben. Ansonsten fällt mir dazu grad nichts ein. :(

**Edit:** Grad nochmal gegoogelt und Shitstorm im Twitter/Internet-Kontext kann man denke ich tatsächlich am besten mit

> Sturm der Entrüstung

bzw.

> Welle der Empörung

übersetzen. Ich nehme aber mal an, dass eben gerade weil diese Begriffe doch sehr "brav" sind, das Wort Shitstorm jetzt auch von deutschen Seiten benutzt wird.

Comment: *Sturm der Entleerung* schösse vermutlich übers Niveau der Leserschaft hinaus. Schade.

Comment: Sturm der Entrüstung trifft es denke ich am besten. Shitstorms sind ein Gruppenphänomen, daher sind deine ersten Antworten leider nicht richtig. +1 fürs brave googeln :)

Comment: Naja, die Frage war erstmal nur, wie man "shitstorm" übersetzt, der Kontext kam erst später. :)

Comment: @toscho: explosive Diar... okay, nee, besser lassen. :D

Answer (score 16):

Folgenden Satz

> We're jumping into a shit storm here.

könnte man mit

> Uns fliegt gleich eine Menge Scheiße um die Ohren.

übersetzen.

---

*Anmerkung:* Beide Redewendungen sind natürlich **vulg.** :-)

Comment: Tipp für vulgäre Redewendungen: Einfach auf Plattdeutsch formulieren, es reichen die vulgären Wörter. Da klingen die meisten Fäkalwörter eher niedlich: *Uns fliegt gleich eine Menge Schiet um die Ohren*...

Comment: @Oreg du meinst doch eher "den Plattdeutschen Begriff verwenden", oder?  ;-)

Comment: @jae: Ja, wie auch immer. Klugschieter ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost womit wir ja wieder beim Thema wären... oder nicht?

Answer (score 10):

Gestern ist der [Shitstorm](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Shitstorm) offiziell in der deutschen Sprache angekommen und wird nun im Duden als

> Sturm der Entrüstung in einem Kommunikationsmedium des Internets, der
>   zum Teil mit beleidigenden Äußerungen einhergeht

definiert.

Comment: Duden ist nicht das Amtsblatt der deutschen Sprache. Duden ist eine Marke der Verlag Bibliographisches Institut GmbH. Dort sind Redakteure beschäftigt, die sich auch einmal irren können oder schlechte Arbeit abliefern. Ich ziehe das Digitale Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache mit seinen Fundstellen im Kontext der vermeintlichen Objektivität der Duden-Redakteure mit ihren konstruierten Beispielsätzen vor.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: es gibt kein Amtsblatt, nur mehr oder weniger gute Wörterbücher. Duden gehört zu den guten Wörterbüchern. Die Definition für *"Shitstorm"* ist ziemlich gut und das Duden Zitat gehört definitiv hierher, Danke Chris.

Comment: @Takkat: seit den Schlechtschreibreformen zählt es für mich nicht mehr zu den guten Wörterbüchern der deutschen Sprache. Daß die Schriftsprache so verstümmelt wurde ist beschämend und es stimmt mich jedesmal traurig wenn ich meine Duden von 1931 und 1965 aufschlage - die einzigen Erinnerungen an eine Zeit vor den Verschlimmbesserungen. Auch Anglizismen (wie shitstorm) finde ich immer wieder zum Kotzen, da sie eine an sich reiche Sprache verkümmern lassen. Aber vielleicht fällt einem das besonders auf wenn man es aus dem Ausland betrachtet. "Welle der Empörung" paßt schon.

Comment: @0xC0000022L *passt

Answer (score 7):

Auf der Seite [false friends, good and bad translation](http://false-friends.crellin.de/) gab's jetzt einen kleinen Artikel zum Wort *Shitstorm*:

[Shitstorm ist ein scheißgefährlicher Begriff!](http://false-friends.crellin.de/2013/07/shitstorm-ist-ein-scheigefahrlicher.html)

Dort heißt es nochmals explizit:

> Ein Shitstorm ist auf Englisch nicht auf Reaktionen im Internet beschränkt.

und des Weiteren:

> Shitstorm ist auf Englisch EXTREM vulgär. Shit ist viel schlimmer als Scheiße.

Auf der Seite werden außerdem folgende Artikel verlinkt.

- [English rude word enters German language](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-23142660)
- [Sh**storm ist auf Englisch ein Bisschen Sch**ße](http://sallymassmann.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/shstorm-ist-auf-englisch-ein-bisschen-schse/)

Bei der Übersetzung des Wortes sollte man also äußerst vorsichtig sein.

Und aller Wahrscheinlichkeit nach, ist Kontext mal wieder gold wert. Man übersetzt nicht einfach das Wort, sondern findet das richtige Wort für den konkreten Kontext. Aber vor allen Dingen das Wichtigste ist: Man übernimmt niemals das Wort aus der einen Sprache direkt in die andere. Da greift man nämlich gründlich in die - ihr wisst schon was.

Answer (score 6):

Bei so einem Wort von einer angemessenen Übersetzung zu sprechen ist vielleicht anmaßend, aber mein Chef hat tatsächlich schon das Wort *Scheißesturm* oder *Scheißeregen* verwendet. Ob das nur eine spaßige Anlehnung an das Original war, vermag ich allerdings nicht zu beurteilen.

Comment: Chefs haben sowieso meistens die kreativeren Schimpfworte als Normalsterbliche. "Klokopf", "Tintenfisch", "Vollzeitbürokrat" -- mmhhh, wunderbar, gleiche Liga wie "Scheißesturm". Vermutlich kreativ konstruiert, nicht in Anlehnung.

Answer (score 5):

Es gibt die Formulierung **"wir kommen in Teufels Küche"**, bedeutet etwa: wir kriegen demnächst ein Problem.

Wenn man sich bereits mitten drin befindet, **"sitzt man in der Patsche"** (oder "in der Scheisse", thx @ladybug).

Man kann auch jemand anderem **"aus der Patsche helfen"**.

Comment: "Wir sitzen ganz schön in der Scheiße"? ^^

Comment: ...oder in der Patsche! Ich werd mal eben editieren.

Comment: Patsche ist prima. +1.

Comment: http://witze.net/witz_5503.html

Comment: @Oreg Patsche ist ne Wucht, mit Patsche macht die Scheisse Spaß  :D

Answer (score 4):

Je nach Kontext würde ich als bedeutungsnäheste Übersetzung:

> You have raised a shit storm.
>
> Da hast du in ein Wespennest gestochen.

oder

> If they deny your application you should raise a shit storm.
>
> Wenn sie deinen Antrag ablehnen, solltest du Himmel und Hölle in Bewegung setzen / keinen Stein auf dem anderen lassen.

vorschlagen.

Comment: Wenn es ein echte Übersetzung sein soll, dann sollte vulgäres auch vulgär übersetzt werden.

Answer (score 3):

Bin mir keiner guten Übersetzung bewusst, zumindest nicht in einem Wort. In einem eher umgangssprachlichen Kontext würde ich es sogar so stehen lassen. "Da kommt viel Scheiße auf uns zu" ist vielleicht noch halbwegs annehmbar, aber auch sehr an den Haaren herbeigezogen.

Für das Wort eine gute deutsche Entsprechung zu finden ist sehr schwer - Allenfalls eine Umschreibung dessen, was das Wort meint ist wohl der sicherste Weg... Man müsste wahrscheinlich den ganzen Satz umstellen.

> Oh - here comes my boss. Shitstorm incoming.
>
> Oh - da kommt mein Chef. Gleich kommt ein Anschiss.

Comment: "Es regnet Scheiße" mag nach einem Chemieunfall angemessen sein, nicht jedoch für einen natürlichen Wolkenbruch.

Comment: Wer redet denn von Wolkenbrüchen?

Comment: @bernd_k: Es kann doch auch Katzen & Hunde regnen, jedenfalls in England ;)

Answer (score 2):

Wie bei so vielen neuen Anglizismen ist das englische Wort mit Ausnahme der Großschreibung auch das deutsche: `der Shitstorm`

Comment: leider. Wobei ich nicht verstehe warum jemand diese Antwort negativ bewertet, wenn sie doch nur eine Tatsache beschreibt. Daher von mir ein Pluspunkt als Ausgleich.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Es ist aber auch nicht richtig, einen Pluspunkt als 'Ausgleich' zu verteilen. - Argument für den Downvote könnte aber sein, dass der englische Begriff viel allgemeiner ist, als er im Deutschen verstanden wird. [Wiki](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shitstorm): "Während mit dem Modebegriff in der Deutschen Sprache ausschließlich ein Internetphänomen gemeint ist, bezeichnet er in er englischen Sprache als Dysphemismus allgemein eine unangenehme Situation." Folglich ist der Downvote doch zu vertreten, sofern dies der Grund ist. Andererseits würde Kommentare helfen.

Comment: @Em1: exakt: "Andererseits würde Kommentare helfen.". Das würde nämlich dem Antwortenden die Möglichkeit geben die Antwort zu verbessern.

Comment: Downvote ist meiner, da diese Antwort nur die Aussage einer früheren Antwort wiederholt, aber dieses Mal ohne Beleg. Im übrigen habe ich noch nie in einem Thread so viele Downvotes vergeben wie hier, es sind sage und schreibe sechs Stück. Einzig der Antwort von splattne gab ich ein Upvote.

Comment: In dem Punkt gebe ich @EugeneSeidel recht. Die Redundanz war mir in dem ganzen "Shitstorm" entgangen. Überhaupt, was suchen hier 11(!) Antworten?

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde **Mistscheiße** vorschlagen.

My Boss here at the university really hates the snow, and uses this expression quite often in Winter.

Er könnte auch für Dich funktionieren ;).

Answer (score 0):

Mein Hirn suchte die Bilderwelt der Jauchegruben, der Kanalisationen und der Klärwerke ab - erfolglos.

Einen bestehenden Ausdruck, der sowohl das derb-vulgäre wie *Scheiße* oder *Jauche* transportiert, als auch die Naturgewalt eines Sturmes wird m.W. von keiner bestehenden Wendung erfasst.

Du musst also selbst tätig werden und etwas schaffen - was nicht verboten ist: Millionen haben es vor uns getan.

> In ein Meer aus Scheiße geraten.

oder

> Von einem Schwall Dünnschiß davongetragen werden.

Fällt mir ein.

Comment: Ich stell mir gerade dein Hirn vor, wie's da durch die Kanalisation... kriecht?  (igitt) Schwimmt?  ;-)

Comment: Guten Appetit bei der Vorstellung. :)

Answer (score 0):

shitstorm bezeichnet im Deutschen einen sehr heftigen Schwall von Beleidigungen
bzw. abwertenden Aussagen. 
Dieses Phänomen ist vor allem durchdie sozialen Netzwerke bekannt geworden.