# "shitstorm" auf Deutsch

Tags: word-usage, anglicism

Jede(r) weiß, was ein ein *shitstorm* ist. Gibt es dafür einen deutschen Ausdruck? In der FAZ wurde vor kurzem [Kritiksturm](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/medien/doku-serie-zur-bild-zeitung-bild-macht-deutschland-bei-amazon-17106991.html?utm_source=pocket-newtab-global-de-DE) verwendet. Für mich klingt das nicht derb genug, um das englische Original wiederzugeben. Immerhin aber ein ernstzunehmender Vorschlag für eine Eindeutschung ...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117442/discussion-on-question-by-kritiker-der-elche-shitstorm-auf-deutsch).

Comment: Zum Thema empfehle ich https://youtu.be/tjMkqFmRGL4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Jede(r) weiß, was ein shitstorm ist.

So könnte man denken, aber wenn man spitzfindig ist, dann ist dem nicht so, denn das englische Wort "shitstorm" entspricht nicht dem "Shitstorm" wie man ihn im Deutschen kennt.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shitstorm) schreibt

> vulgar slang : a wildly chaotic and unmanageable situation, controversy, or sequence of events

Cambridge Dictionary dagegen definiert es als

> a situation in which a lot of people are disagreeing and arguing with each other:

und das [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shitstorm) gibt noch ein paar andere umgangsprachliche Bedeutungen.

Keine der ganzen Definitionen umfasst allerdings das, was man im Deutschen gemeinhin unter einem Shitstorm versteht:

> "das lawinenartige Auftreten negativer Kritik bis hin zur Schmähkritik im Rahmen von sozialen Netzwerken, Blogs oder Kommentarfunktionen von Internetseiten"

([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shitstorm))

Daher kann man hier von einem [Neologismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologismus), bzw. [Scheinanglizismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheinanglizismus) sprechen.

Beispiele dafür gibt es im Deutschen zuhauf. Handy, Oldtimer oder Hometrainer sind Wörter die englisch klingen, im Englischen möglicherweise sinnvoll sind, aber etwas ganz anderes (Handy, Oldtimer) oder sogar gar nichts (Hometrainer) bedeuten.

Also, obwohl es gewisse Überschneidungen gibt, muss man sagen: shitstorm != Shitstorm

<sub>(Hinweis: Hier bei German SE wurde auch schon versucht das [englische shitstorm zu übersetzen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/445/was-ist-eine-angemessene-%C3%9Cbersetzung-f%C3%BCr-shitstorm). Die Trennung der Bedeutungen [dt./engl. s.o.] ist dort aber auch nicht zu 100% gegeben)</sub>

---

Nachdem das viel zu breit dargelegt wurde kann man die Frage allerdings umstellen:

> Gibt es ein keine (englischen) Lehnwörter enthaltenes deutsches Wort für Shitstorm?

Also analog zur denkbaren Frage: Was ist ein *deutscheres* Wort für [Portemonnaie](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Portemonnaie) (ursprünglich franz.) und man käme auf Begriffe wie Brieftasche oder Geldbörse.

<sub>Anm.: Portemonnaie hat dieselbe Bedeutung Brieftasche/Geldbörse, passt also nicht zu 100%, aber mir fällt gerade kein besseres Beispiel ein. ^^</sub>

Hier stellt sich mir eine Frage. Braucht man das? Selbsternannte Sprachschützer [versuchten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobiltelefon#Entstehung_der_Bezeichnung_%E2%80%9EHandy) auch schon aus dem Handy ein Händi zu machen. Wir könnten uns nun natürlich Wörter ausdenken, wie das in der Frage bereits genannte *Kritiksturm*. Auch andere Wortbildungen wären denkbar, aber all denen fehlt etwas entscheidendes: die Verbreitung in der Bevölkerung und auch die von dir angedeutete *sprachliche Wucht* + Derbheit. Was die Zukunft bringt kann allerdings niemand sagen, da wir aber mittlerweile so sehr an englische Begriffe gewöhnt sind kann ich mir nicht vorstellen, dass sich mittelfristig eine Alternative etablieren wird.

Dementsprechend, und nachdem die Antwort viel länger ausfiel als ich wollte: **Nein, es gibt (noch) kein anderes (akzeptiertes) deutsches Wort für Shitstorm und Shitstorm ist ein eigenständiges [deutsches Wort](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Shitstorm).**

---

Weitere Links

[Shitstorm ist ein deutsches Wort](https://www.engelhardt.at/shitstorm-ist-ein-deutsches-wort/)

[Englisch hat ein deutsches Wort für Shitstorm](https://www.welt.de/kultur/article152952094/Englisch-hat-ein-deutsches-Wort-fuer-Shitstorm.html)

Answer (score 5):

Das deutsche Wort für *shitstorm* ist

> Shitstorm

Quelle: [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/shitstorm)

Während  das englische Wort als *"umgangssprachlich, vulgär"* markiert ist, ist es als Fremdwort in einem deutschsprachigen Kontext nur *"umgangssprachlich*, aber nicht vulgär.

---

Man muss nicht immer alles eindeutschen. Die deutsche Sprache verfügt über das wunderbare Feature der Assimilationsfähigkeit. Man kann beliebige Wörter einer anderen Sprache ganz einfach in den deutschen Wortschatz integrieren. Dabei muss man in der Schriftform nur gegebenenfalls eine Transliteration in die lateinische Schrift durchführen (aus »степь« wird »Steppe«, aus »الكحول« wird »Alkohol«, aus »κλίμα« wird »Klima«).

Durch längeren Gebrauch, oder auch aus Unwissenheit, wird zuerst die Aussprache und später auch die Rechtschreibung an deutsche Verhältnisse angepasst (aus englisch *jute,* Aussprache [dʒuːt], also ungefähr *»dschuut«,* wird »Jute« [ˈjuːtə]) und irgendwann nehmen die deutschen Muttersprachler diese Wörter gar nicht mehr als Fremd wahr.

Wie groß der Anteil der Fremdwörter und Lehnwörter in der deutschen Sprache ist, kann daher auch nur schwer abgeschätzt werden, eben weil viele Wörter, die uns so vertraut sind wie echte Erbwörter, in Wahrheit aus anderen Sprachen importiert wurden:

- Lateinisch: Fenster, Frucht, Koch, Kessel, Meister, Mühle, Nase, nüchtern, Ordnung, Pfirsich
- Griechisch: Auto, Foto, Idee, Chor, Logik, Diät, Idiot
- Italienisch: Bank, Rest, Kartoffel, Porzellan
- Hebräisch: Ganove, Kaff, kotzen, schachern, zocken
- Französisch: Beton, Hotel, Büro, (sich) blamieren
- Polnisch: Gurke, Peitsche, Säbel, Stieglitz, Zeisig
- Tschechisch: Roboter, Pistole, Trabant
- Türkisch: Joghurt, Kaviar, Kiosk
- Ungarisch: Kutsche, Paprika, Tollpatsch

Und natürlich werden auch aus der dem Deutschen sehr ähnlichen Weltsprache Englisch viele Wörtern in den deutschen Wortschatz aufgenommen, und dieser Prozess ist zwar schon lange im Gange, nahm aber vor allem nach dem zweiten Weltkrieg auch an Intensität zu. Daher stammen neue Fremdwörter vor allem aus dieser Sprache.

Eine im Internet verfügbare [Quelle (pdf)](https://www.ram-verlag.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/g7zeit.pdf#page=28) berichtet, dass ca. 3% der im deutschen Wortschatz verwendeten Wörter aus dem Englischen stammen, 8% aus dem Französischen und 12% aus der lateinischen Sprache. Dabei wurden nur Wörter gezählt, die in der jeweiligen Sprache entstanden sind. Betrachtete man auch Vermittlersprachen (Beispiel: Ketchup wurde aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche importiert, ist aber in der Chinesischen Sprache entstanden: 茄汁 = Tomatensauce), dann kommt man auf noch höhere Prozentzahlen.

---

Die Fähigkeit, Wörter aus fremden Sprachen in unsere eigene zu integrieren, sollten wir als positive Eigenschaft verstehen. Ohne sie wäre unsere Sprache erheblich ärmer und ausdrucksschwächer. Und sie leidet darunter auch nicht. Sie verändert sich nur, aber Veränderung ist eine unabdingbare Eigenschaft von Entwicklung.

Answer (score 4):

Das deutsche "Shitstorm" kann man natürlich verwenden, und wenn man es derb ausdrücken möchte, passt das ja nicht schlecht. Es ist halt im Englischen sehr vulgär und deshalb kaum als sachliche Beschreibung eines Ereignisses zu benutzen, und es ist auch nicht besonders differenziert. Ich finde den Ansatz  gut, stattdessen lieber je nach dem Ereignis, das man beschreiben möchte, passendere Wörter zu erfinden, wie es die FAZ hier macht. Die deutsche Sprache übernimmt ja nicht nur gern Lehnwörter, sondern hat auch die Besonderheit, dass man neue Wörter bei Bedarf im Vorbeigehen zusammenbauen kann.

Ausdrücke, die ich gelesen oder gehört habe: **Kritiksturm, Proteststurm, Sturm der Empörung, Empörungswelle, Aufschrei der Entrüstung, Sturm der Entrüstung, wüste Beschimpfungen, wütende Gegenrede, empörter Widerspruch, Trollaufstand, Sofarevolution.**

Comment: ""Empörungswelle" und " Trollaufstand" gefallen mir gut.